# Having a tough time with this probability exercise

Tags: probability

I know that for number 7 it is implied that Y is independent from X and has uniform distribution (0,1). I also know that I should use the convolution formula but I'm just not positive on how to bound the integral. Anyone mind lending me a hand on this one? http://tinypic.com/r/2jahnuv/8[1]
Many thanks